# How to correct event propagation in case of multilayer component

Tags: react-native

I have 2 View component rendered over each other using absolute positioning. Both view have onPress events binded using TouchableOpacity. Now when I press top view actually below view onPress event is triggered and top one remains as it is. What am I doing wrong here?

Top Layer Code

```
<TouchableOpacity style={cell} onPress={this.handleMessangerPress}>
     <Image style={[filterImage, {marginLeft: 20}]} source={{ uri: imagePath + 'messanger.png' }} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Bottom Layer Code

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.subTotal} onPress={this.handleSubTotalPress}>
    <View>
       <Text style={styles.text}>{'Subtotal Rs.' + total}</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

In above case handleSubTotalPress is getting called in place of handleMessangerPress

Comment: Are these buttons positioned on top of one another? The way react-native event handling works isn't like how you're expecting, the bottom most element is always going to be the responder. You can use `View` components with gesture responders to control which item gets to be the responder on touch but it's a bit complicated. I would just change the position of these buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.subTotal} onPress={()=> this.handleSubTotalPress() }>
```

or

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.subTotal} onPress={this.handleSubTotalPress.bind(this) }>
```